# What property is shared between the universal set and the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What property is shared between the universal set and the empty set?

I was once told of such a property, but I honestly cannot remember what that property was.

Comment: They are both open and closed for any topology?

Comment: They are both sets.

Comment: The property "X is the universal set or the empty set"?

Comment: What do you mean with universal set?

Comment: They both satisfy $\forall x,y: x\in S \leftrightarrow y\in S$?

Comment: @Uncountable I think your right! Now I remember.

Comment: @Uncountable I do not know what that means, "both are open and closed for any topology," but I think that was what it was. May you provide an explanation on what that means? Thanks.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topology $\mathcal {T} $ on a set $ X $ is a collection of subsets of $ X $ satisfying some basic axioms. One of the axioms is that $\emptyset $ and $ X $ are both in $\mathcal {T} $. If a subset $ A $ of $ X $ is in the topology, we call $ A $ open. If the complement of a subset is in the topology, we call it closed. Now from the axiom stated above it follows directly that $\emptyset $ and $ X $ are both open and closed for any topology $\mathcal {T} $ on $ X $.

The other axioms are that unions of opens are open, and finite intersections of opens are open.